# How to decrease the line height in ckeditor 4.4.5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can the default line-height be reduced on the ck-editor. It's little too high at the moment, since I have upgraded it to the version 4.4.5

Is there any property available to do this?

Comment: `#cke_1_contents { line-height: /* whatever */ }`?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. Its for the contents within the editor.

Comment: Yeah, I later saw that it was inside an `iframe`... There is a line-height plugin, but it only adds to the line-height... Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was upgrading ckeditor to 4.6.2 and ran across the same problem again. The problem was the line height was more when i pressed enter key to go to the next line. This time I found a new solution.

ckeditor adds `<p>` tags instead of `<br>` tags on clicking Enter. This is its default behaviour. We can change this to either `<br>` or `<div>` tags based on what is required.

There is a config.js file in the ckeditor library with the below code:

`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {};`

You can update this function with any of the below properties:

```
CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV – new <div> blocks are created
CKEDITOR.ENTER_P – new <p> paragraphs are created
CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR – new <br> line breaks are created.
```

Example:

`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
};`

Comment: You should make this the accepted answer. Good job! No other Google resources have this solution.

Comment: @BinodKalathil no other Google resource shows this solution because it's a crappy one. The BR mode is not recommended. If you want to modify line height you can do this with CSS. Just keep the `ENTER_P` mode and add `p { margin : 0; }` to the `contents.css` file in case of classic editor or main CSS file in case of inline editor. Of course same styling should be used on target page (where content will be published). This is the correct solution and not the bug-prone BR mode. Another solution is the one provided below by @Reema which in general is about CSS modification.

Answer (score 4):

There is a file `contents.css` in the ckeditor library with the class `.cke_editable` with the `line-height` property set to `1.6`. Update it with the value required. This will update the line-height in all the places its used in your application.

This is what i did.

```
.cke_editable
{
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why wouldn't changes to `contents.css` take effect? I'm trying to change the line height too—and a few other things—but even if I change this rule in the file, the page actually loads kind of an old version of it, which I don't know where it gets it from. I'm using `django-ckeditor`

Answer (score -1):

To increase or decrease the line height in CKEditor 4.17.2, you can use the Line Height plugin. Here's how you can enable and configure it:

1. Download the Line Height plugin: Go to the CKEditor Plugin Repository (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lineheight) and download the Line Height plugin for CKEditor 4.
2. Include the Line Height plugin in your CKEditor setup: Add the Line Height plugin files to your CKEditor installation. Extract the downloaded plugin and place the plugin files (e.g., `lineheight` folder) inside the `plugins` directory of your CKEditor installation.
3. Enable the Line Height plugin: Open the CKEditor configuration file (`config.js` or `config.js.php` in your CKEditor installation directory) and add the following line:

   ```js
   config.extraPlugins = 'lineheight';
   ```

   This line instructs CKEditor to load the Line Height plugin when it initializes.
4. Configure the line height options: In the same configuration file, you can set the available line height options. Add the following lines to specify the line heights you want to offer:

   ```js
   config.line_height = '1;1.5;2;2.5;3'; // Example values, customize as needed
   ```

   In this example, line height options of 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, and 3 will be available in the CKEditor toolbar.
5. Save and use CKEditor: Save the configuration file and integrate CKEditor into your webpage as you normally would. The Line Height plugin should now be enabled, and you should see the line height options in the CKEditor toolbar.

By selecting the desired text in CKEditor and using the line height options in the toolbar, you can increase or decrease the line height of the selected text.

Note: If you encounter any issues during the process, please refer to the plugin documentation or CKEditor's official documentation for further assistance.